# jQuery Mobile video website, convert to PhoneGap app with videos on SD card instead of streamed

Tags: html, jquery-mobile, cordova, html5-video, smartphone

I have a jQuery Mobile website I created for a friend/client of mine. It only has 6 pages or so (2 of them are dialog windows). The site has HTML5 video with fallback for flash support via the videojs library. All videos are encoded properly in mp4, ogv (theora), and webm and so far play on every device I have used.

My problem lies bandwidth, the purpose of the program really needs to be an application because these are informational videos that may need to be viewed at any time, even with no web access (web access is required for first login to verify credentials).

I was left with 3 solutions, try writing native apps for all the platforms myself in their native languages, use Sencha Touch (which I am comfortable enough with extJS to do), or taking my existing jquery mobile app that is 100% functional including log-in and some backend package management to assign users a package of videos (there are multiple packages each with between 8-20 videos), and follow the jQuery Mobile tutorial for getting your app ready for PhoneGap, I believe its only enabling two settings, and both are to enable "cross-domain" requests, since my current web app would be running as localhost, it would see the scripts as external pages.

My main question/problem is for one, I have never used PhoneGap; aside from their Hello World android tutorial, and I know there are other all-in-one frameworks out there now: PhoneGap, Titanium, Corona, Adobe Flex (which I am installing while writing this tutorial, to see what it has to offer. If it has features like encoding videos automatically for the target device (video resolution changing), or even has local video playback features at all that may work.

Does anyone know which of the current frameworks have the ability to install a set of videos to the sdcard, (totaling around 6mb per install), and play them natively (by that i mean, in the devices native player, not inline inside of a webview). Which on android phones anyways, my current videojs based player plays the files natively in everything I have tried it on.

I just need a push in the right direction, if there is a PhoneGap plugin that I don't know about that allows videos to be played from the sd card, that would be terrific. Although I am not very happy with the speed of the android and blackberry webview controls. So something that uses 100% native controls would be great. I hope you guys can come up with some ideas, you can see the current app in action at [m.yourvideobenefits.com](http://m.yourvideobenefits.com) email:abc@tool.com password: demo

You should view it from your phone if you want to see it properly, but if you do not have a smart phone; keep in mind that when viewing this page certain desktop browsers, the videos become their actual size after they are through loading. This is because i have `autoload="true"` in the video tag (which is ignored on most phones, but believe it or not, setting `autoload="true"` is what actually allowed the videos to not play inline on certain devices. A bug on the device, I am sure...but without this tag the videos played inline on iPhone 4 with the latest iOS version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it very easily with phonegap; you already have your web page, so it would be much less work, probably.

You could get the videos from inside your apps bundle in ios, and then it wouldn't be hard to select the one with the best resolution for the device being used. You could also download the videos at the perfect format and resolution the first time your app plays from your server using the file api. That convined with the storage api is nice for actualizations.

There's a plugin I use for android, because video tag is sometimes bugged or doesn't work at all in older versions, https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/VideoPlayer.
It only plays from web or sdcard, but that's rarely too bad.

I can't help you with black berry, but I'm pretty sure there must be a way of doing it. And, anyway, appcelerator doesn't support it yet, so you would probably had to do it natively. Even if there isn't a plugin for black berry, you'd probably have to chose between native developement and html5 player inside phonegap. I won't give you my opinion about it here, for I'm not the one to give it and Stack Overflow says I shouln'd give it anyway.

Comment: Also, in case you use it, it might help to stop using jquery mobile --or any other javascript not really necesary for that mather --in the page with the html5 video player to make it smoother. It has helped me when using canvas. You just need to not use ajax when linking to that page and, of course, do not load jquery mobile in that page.

Comment: Thanks, my current encodes play fine streaming on all devices i've tried (I only tried the known buggy ones) Just an FYI to you, encode your videos with Handbrake to an IPhone/IPod setting, and MAKE SURE you check Web Optimized (it does 2 pass encoding and allows android to stream it)..oh yeah even though handbrake says its outputting an mp4, it is an m4v; just rename the extension and it plays on any H264 device, I also use Firefogg for my ogv and webm. But you saying I should include no bulky js frameworks on my video pages so the html5 player runs faster? If so, that works with no changes

Comment: Thanks for the encoding tips, I didn't know all of them. I'm saying it might help, I always do it, anyway; I think it helps, not only on videos but other things, and it's very noticeable on canvas or things that depend on a timer. With android, I recommend you use the plug in for native video player, because old devices or versions of OS sometimes don't support the video tag.